# wildfly Failed to define class java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError plus Mysql module not working

Tags: java, mysql, ejb, wildfly

When I start the wildfly server it shows me the java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError, which I get is that the class was compiled by a more recent version.

I tried to check the enviroment vars to check if they were wrong and stuff, and all of them point to the right versions of the jdk/jre which is 1.8. I guess that when i started building the project i used java 11 which was by default on Eclipse, but i have not installed Java SE 11 cause it gave me some problems on the past.

```
17:29:33,684 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-5) Failed to define class ejbRemote.PersonaBean in Module "deployment.ejbRemote.jar" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Failed to link ejbRemote/PersonaBean (Module "deployment.ejbRemote.jar" from Service Module Loader): ejbRemote/PersonaBean has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:839)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:14)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:84)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1737)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1699)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1557)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

After this it repeats the same error a couple of times.

I was trying to add to the wildfly server the mysql module and i've created the folders at modules\system\layers\base\com\mysql\main but i also think i made a mistake and "broke" the server.

````
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="com.mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar" />
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>```

Please help. Thanks
````

Comment: So what is your question?  You've got a Java version mismatch - fix that first.  Then I don't understand what your issue is with MySQL.

Comment: basically the question is: how do i change the versions on eclipse, and if installing the mysql module for wildfly could actually made it worse, since after i tried that, it doesn't even start the server

Comment: As for the java version, use same version for building your project and running wildfly. As for the mysql thing, you haven't provided any error. `module.xml` seems ok. Finally provide wildfly version.

Comment: I found what was the problem. I still had in the deployment folder an old compiled class that was causing the freaking error. I deleted all the related files of it. Now everything works. xD